# How can I upgrade python3.7.8 to python 3.7.13 on windows?

Tags: python

I want to upgrade the python 3.7.8  version to python 3.7.13 but python version 3.7.13 exe is not available. Please let me know how we can create an executable for windows 10. If anyone has the python executable file for please provide me link.

Answer (score 2):

Release 3.7.13 is currently at the security phase stage so I think those executables will not be available. May be you can install the final bugfix release in the 3.7 release i.e 3.7.9.
So may be You can upgrade from 3.7.8 to 3.7.9

Reference:
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3713/

Comment: yes, but do you know how to create executable python.exe? if yes let, please sent me a necessary link or any documentation

Comment: the fixes that are done in 3.7.13, Is it available at 3.7.9?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official release packages available. As mentioned by @Chatla-harishwar, the official release are available only till 3.7.9.

Try this : [Python Windows Unofficial](https://github.com/adang1345/PythonWindows/tree/master/3.7.13)

Comment: fixes that are done in 3.7.13, is it available at 3.7.9? Please let me know